# Finding first non-empty subtype in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a C++ metafunction that returns to me the first non-empty sub-type for the provided template parameters.

For example:

```cpp
struct I { using subtype = int; };
struct D { using subtype = double; };
struct E { using subtype = empty ; };
```

I'm trying to achieve:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same<int, first_non_empty_subtype<E,E,I>>::value, "the first non-empty subtype should be 'int'");
static_assert(std::is_same<double, first_non_empty_subtype<E,D,I>>::value, "the first non-empty subtype should be 'double'");
static_assert(std::is_same<empty, first_non_empty_subtype<E,E,E>>::value, "since all subtypes are empty, the result is empty");
```

My initial thoughts are to use `std::conditional_t` with template recursion:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using first_non_empty_subtype = std::conditional_t<
    !std::is_empty<typename T::subtype>::value, 
    typename T::subtype, 
    first_non_empty_subtype<Ts...>>::type
```

However, I'm not all familiar with implementing template recursion for type aliases.

Can someone help point me in the right direction for solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: For recursion to work, you need something that breaks the recursion. In your example there is no such thing, and AFAIK it can't be done with template aliases, you can't specialize them in any way. You can make a recursive struct that only holds a `using subtype = ...` and use that. If you want you can then make template alias that points at the recursive struct for easier use.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I intentionally left that out because I wasn't sure how it would be implemented. Thanks for explaining how template aliases can't be specialized -- @max66 shows a solution that uses a recursive struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose something as follows

```
// ground case: no more types, so empty
template <typename ...>
struct fnes_helper
 { using type = empty; };

// the first type is T and isn't empy; so T
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct fnes_helper<T, Ts...>
 { using type = T; };

// the first type is empty; so recursion
template <typename ... Ts>
struct fnes_helper<empty, Ts...> : public fnes_helper<Ts...>
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
using first_non_empty_subtype 
   = typename fnes_helper<typename Ts::subtype...>::type;
```

Observe that the `fnes_helper` more specialized version is the one with the `empty` type in first position, so is the version used in that case.
Follows the other specialization, the one with a generic `T` type in first position and finally we have the main version that is selected in the other cases, so where the list of types is empty.

Also remember to add a `{}` or a `::value` after `std::is_same` in the `static_assert()` tests

```
static_assert(std::is_same<int, first_non_empty_subtype<E,E,I>>{},
              "the first non-empty subtype should be 'int'");
static_assert(std::is_same<double, first_non_empty_subtype<E,D,I>>{},
              "the first non-empty subtype should be 'double'");
static_assert(std::is_same<empty, first_non_empty_subtype<E,E,E>>{},
              "since all subtypes are empty, the result is empty");
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! This was what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick response and for taking the time to explain how the solutions works.